# XML Deserialize with same element name and different attributes​ name

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-serialization

I want to deseralize following XML in C#

```
<Test>
<Testdata>
<abc name = "fname"> Test</abc>
<abc name = "lname"> Name</abc
</Testdata>
</Test>
```

I have a small example, I have much larger XML which needs to deseralize into .Net objects!! Below is object I have

```
Public class Employee
{
      Public string LastName {get; set;}
      Public string FirstName {get;set;}
}
```

How do I deseralize such xml using either linq or XML serializer.

Currently I am using xdocument, getting all node with name abc and using if else ladder constructing the object but that is not the right way.

Test is first name
Name is last name in the XML..

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: can I check... is `Test` the `FirstName` value?, and `Name` the `LastName` value?

Comment: @marc Yes sir!!

Answer (score 0):

The mapping you describe is not one that is supported by `XmlSerializer`. You cannot serialize `Employee` in that way without one of:

- implementing `IXmlSerializable` - which I do *not* recommend; very easy to make a mess of this, particularly the deserialization code
- doing it manually via `XDocument` or `XmlDocument` (again, quite a bit of work)
- creating a DTO model that is usable from `XmlSerializer` that matches your schema

Frankly, I would use the last option, which probably means creating something like (completely untested, but I'll try it in a minute):

```
[XmlRoot("Test")]
public class DtoRoot {
    [XmlArray("Testdata")]
    [XmlArrayItem("abc")]
    public List<KeyValuePair> Items {get;} = new List<KeyValuePair>();

    public string this[string key] => Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == key)?.Value;
}
public class KeyValuePair{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Key {get;set;}
    [XmlText]
    public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

and use something like:

```
Employee emp = new Employee
{
    FirstName = "Fred",
    LastName = "Flintstone"
};
var obj = new DtoRoot {
    Items = {
    new KeyValuePair { Key = "fname", Value = emp.FirstName },
    new KeyValuePair { Key = "lname", Value = emp.LastName},
} };
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DtoRoot));
ser.Serialize(Console.Out, obj);
```

which gives us (ignore the `encoding` - that is because of `Console.Out`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<Test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Testdata>
    <abc name="fname">Fred</abc>
    <abc name="lname">Flintstone</abc>
  </Testdata>
</Test>
```

To deserialize: deserialize into a `DtoRoot` instance, then use the indexer:

```
var obj = (DtoRoot)ser.Deserialize(source);
var emp = new Employee {
    FirstName = obj["fname"],
    LastName = obj["lname"],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with parsing xml into classes using xdocument instead of serializing.  Here is a method without using else ladder

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication49
{   
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Employee.employees = doc.Descendants("Testdata").Select(x => new Employee()
            {
                FirstName = x.Elements().Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("name") == "fname").Select(y => (string)y).FirstOrDefault(),
                LastName = x.Elements().Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("name") == "lname").Select(y => (string)y).FirstOrDefault()
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class Employee
    {
        public static List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

        public string LastName {get; set;}
        public string FirstName {get;set;}
    }


}
```

Comment: No faster or no slower than any other xml method.  Only if you have huge xml files does it pay to use an XmlReader.  The speed in this case has more do do with the style of your xml using same tag for both first and last name.

Comment: I believe you big where condition to handle nulls?

Comment: You posted sample code so I wasn't sure if null checking was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use List as here.

```
public class Employee
{
    public static List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

    public Listc<string> Name {get; set;}
}
```